# How to store a text lib in an efficient way

Tags: c#, struct, static, heap-memory, stack-memory

I would ask you what you think about the method I use to store a lot of string constant that I use in my program.

The goal is not to block memory resources and have some text string used for, an example, a debugger, but not only, basically its a text library used in all my program with some default text string.

I first thought about a singleton class but I don't know if it would be more efficient in this case, while singleton is in the heap and not cool for memory issues while the struct is normally in the stack and seeing microsoft advice would be more efficient.

here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show(Library.Apps_txt.resultvalue);
  //I want to be able to call that in any form or class using this namespace
    }
}
public class Library
{
    public struct Apps_txt
    {
        public static String resultvalue { get { return "result value IS: "; } }
        public static String Pbexcept { get { return "Exception has raised."; } }
        //thousand of string.
        //...
        public static String mystring1000000 { get { return "my string 1000000"; } }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered using resource files?

Comment: Why not just trust the compiler to store it and generate code to access it in the most efficient manner? Premature optimization being the root of all evil and all...

Comment: Your assertion that a singleton is on the heap and a struct is normally on the stack is not correct. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/, as well as the part 2 (linked from that article). You probably want to use a [resource file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx). If you want to do it in code, however, don't get hung up on class versus struct and how the runtime organizes the data in memory. Write it so that it's easy to understand and use. Memory and access speed will not be issues.